# Facebook API - return friends list (PHP arrays)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im trying to return the friend list of a user using a Facebook app without using the PHP SDK.
I have managed to return the users name, gender, etc. without using an auth code. Im now trying to return a list of names who are the users friends, all ive managed to do so far is print the array, I cant seem to only print the name as its laid out differently to the users name, gender, etc. which I managed to echo by doing:

```
$user->name
```

But when I try that for the friends list it doesnt work and doesnt echo anything at all, I was just wondering if anyone knew how I go about doing this?

Using print_r I get the following:

```
Array(
[0] => Array ( [name] => Friend's name [id] => x )
[1] => Array ( [name] => Friend's name [id] => x )
[2] =>....)
```

Until all of the friends have been listed.

---

```
 { "name": "Name", 
    "hometown": {
      "id": "Hometown_id", 
      "name": "Hometown"
    }, 
    "id": "Friend_id" }
```

Above is the structure of the array of each, I think a potential issue is that not everybody has a hometown set which may be why I'm receiving a forEach error?

Comment: Do you have the proper permissions?

Comment: Yes im using oauth_token and I can print the whole array but I only want the names

Comment: Why don't you just access the array in the normal way you do in php?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: What are you doing to try to access the names? Just checking, but you are using $arr[0]['name'] instead of just $arr['name'] or $arr[0], right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that array structure, it's pretty simple(in php) to get what you want.  I recommend reading from php's manual on [arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.array.php).

Just try something like this:

```
foreach ($array as $inner_array) {
    echo $inner_array['name'] . "<br />";
}
```

Aside from that, it would be...

```
echo $your_array[0]['name'];
echo $your_array[1]['name'];
```

And so on and so fourth..

**Update:**

What you are now looking is not an array, but a javascript object.  It is referred to as **JSON**: Javascript Object Notation.

You need a special parser to interpret it as an array: [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), which comes shipped with php greater than or equal to 5.2.0.  To make the array associative, you must pass a second parameter, a boolean, `true`.  It defaults to `false` otherwise.  An example of usage:

```
$json = '{ "name": "Name", 
    "hometown": {
      "id": "Hometown_id", 
      "name": "Hometown"
    }, 
    "id": "Friend_id" }';

$json_arr = json_decode($json,true);

foreach ($json_arr as $key => $var) {
    if (!is_array($var)) {
        if ($key == 'name') {
            echo $var . "<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 2:**

```
foreach ($json_arr as $key => $var) {
    if (!is_array($var)) {
        if ($key == 'name') {
            echo "Name: " . $var . "<br />";
        }
    }
    else {
        if ($key == 'hometown') {
            echo "Hometown: " . $var['name'] . "<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

The above should do what you need.

Comment: Exactly what I was after, just tried it now and it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Sorry, I just realised that I need to include some friend details so cannot use "/me/friends/" and have had to use the official URL from the API which returns different information in a similar array. I've been able to return the names successfully but the hometown, birthday, etc. are in arrays within again the friend array, I was wondering if you could help me modify the code you posted earlier in order to return the other details. I've tried myself but I'm getting a for each error so I think I'm doing something wrong? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for your reply although I cant get your posted code to work. I was already json_decoding the values to retrieve the users name. The first code segment you posted was perfect in that it printed a plain list of the users friends, now all I want to do is post the users hometown too

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I really do appreciate the help youre giving me. Now its simply displaying "Hometown: 'Friend's name'" for every person and the actual users hometown is nowhere to be seen, is it me doing something wrong? I think thats quite likely to be fair!

Comment: @thrash Without seeing the array, I'm pretty much shooting in the dark currently.  Hopefully my most recent update, which adds in a check, will do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to work with querying specific data from Facebook is FQL. Check out https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/ and let me know if that's what you're looking for.

The sample on the link I provided will grab all of the active user's friends. If you use the sample as a starter (having filled in all the proper info for your app along with a valid access token), then go to the area where it says `// run fql query` and change `uid2` to `name` in the following line:

```
fql?q=SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1=me()
```

Adding the following to the end of the script would then populate all of the friends' names into the array called `$names`

```
$r = $fql_multiquery_obj['data'][0]['fql_result_set'];
foreach ($r as $u)
{
    $name[count($name)] = $u['name'];
}
```

Does that help you do what you're trying to do? Let me know :)